Sharepoint Online Embedding Issue: Manual vs Programmatic File Upload
I am trying to embed an aspx file in a Sharepoint page (with the file stored in SiteAssets), but have discovered that Sharepoint behaves differently based on how I upload the file.
If I upload it manually and click "Replace" in the toast-like popdown in the upper right after the initial upload, I am able to view the rendered aspx page directly in a tab and in an embed web part. On the other hand, if I upload it via script (my goal), whether it be MSGraph or PnP Powershell, the upload succeeds, but I get an error page titled "Something went wrong" with subheading "file not found" when attempting to view the file both in a tab and in the embed web part.
The file has not moved. It is in the same location and and if I replace it again manually, all goes back to working properly. I also can download the file after a scripted upload and the file is not corrupted. I can manually re-upload the downloaded file and it will be rendered.
For reference, the relevant portion of my PnP script:
$ConnectionSplat = @{
  Tenant          = $Tenant
  Url             = $TenantUrl
  ClientId        = $ClientId
  CertificatePath = $CertPath
}   
$connection = Connect-PnPOnline  @ConnectionSplat -ReturnConnection
$List = 'SiteAssets'
$UploadSplat = @{
  Path       = $Path
  Connection = $connection
  Folder     = $List
}
Add-PnPFile @UploadSplat

The script itself is not the problem however, but the fact of having uploaded the file that way, for some reason.
The only lead I found was someone mentioning in a github issue that the Author/Editor field being set to Sharepoint App rather than an actual user might cause an issue, but even setting that via the following just after the Add-PnPFile did not resolve the issue (I confirmed the property actually got set on the file):
$ListItemSplat = @{
  Connection = $connection
  List       = $List
  Identity   = $FileId
  UpdateType = "UpdateOverwriteVersion"
}
Set-PnPListItem @ListItemSplat -Values @{ModifiedBy = $UserUpn }

After a couple of days of researching this issue and trying some things, I am stumped. I hope someone can shed some light on this.
EDIT:
This blog post describes something similar to what I am experiencing, but for me it only occurs with script-uploaded aspx files. He makes an interesting point about permissions, but in his case, user permissions. I have tested various API permissions on the application registration I use for the script and nothing has changed the situation any. So odd...
